# How to set outgoing nodes in Cypher?

Tags: variables, set, cypher

I have a simple query: given a node A, count the number of nodes that node A has outgoing links, then set that number as a property of A. However I just can't do it.

## Attempt 1

```sql
MATCH (n)-->(m) 
SET n.out=count(m)
RETURN n.name,n.out
```

This yields the error:

```
Invalid use of aggregating function count(...) in this context (line 2, column 11 (offset: 28))
"set n.out=count(m)"
           ^
```

## Attempt 2

```sql
MATCH (n)-->(m) 
WITH count(m) AS o 
SET n.out=o 
RETURN n.name,n.out
```

This yields the error:

```
Variable `n` not defined (line 3, column 5 (offset: 43))
"SET n.out=o"
     ^
```

In both times the errors are in the SET clause. But reading the [documentation for `SET`](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/set/#set-set-a-property) I cannot identify why these happen.

<sub>I cannot count the links because for one pair of n, m there maybe several link types.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the desired outcome with the following query:

```
MATCH (n)
WITH size((n)-->()) as out, n
SET n.out = out
RETURN n.name, n.out
```

Comment: Can you tell why the codes I made don't work? Also, in your `WITH` clause, what does `, n` in the end mean?